# Getting attendance in percentage

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to get the percentage of attendance in that if someone attends for 3 days the score will be 100%, 2 days it will be 67% and so on.

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\JEFF\PycharmProjects\project\janlogs.xlsx', parse_dates=['Date/Time'])
df2 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Name", "Date"])
weekly_totals = df2.groupby(['Name', 'Week']
).agg(
    {
         'Date': ['count']
    }
)

# print (weekly_totals)

weekly_table = pd.pivot_table(weekly_totals, columns='Week',  values=['Date'],
                              index=['Name'],
                              fill_value=0, dropna=True)
```

So far I,ve been able to get the number of days attended per week.

```
Week                      2  3  4  5  6
Name                                   
Bruce Wayne               3  1  3  2  0
Agnes Wayua               0  0  1  0  0
Alexandra Cronberg        2  2  2  2  0
```

Any way I can convert these attendances into percentage such that if the attendance is 3 it translates to 100% if it's 2 it translates to 67% and so on.

Comment: help out please